# Word Sense Disambiguation using WordNet.Net

Tags: nlp, wordnet, word-sense-disambiguation

I need to do some word sense disambiguation as part of a larger project and I came across [WordNet.Net](http://opensource.ebswift.com/WordNet.Net/Introduction.aspx)
I tried to use the wordsensedisambiguator class that came with the WordsMatching project in the download, here is my code

```
        string sent = "We have investigated the inductions of the IE genes in response to calcium signals in Jurkat cells (in the presence of activated p21(ras)) and their correlated consequences.";
        Tokeniser tok = new Tokeniser();
        tok.UseStemming = true;
        string[] words = tok.Partition(sent);

        if (words.Length == 0) return null;

        MyWordInfo[] wordInfos = new MyWordInfo[words.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
        {

            WnLexicon.WordInfo wordInfo = WnLexicon.Lexicon.FindWordInfo(words[i], true);

            if (wordInfo.partOfSpeech != Wnlib.PartsOfSpeech.Unknown && wordInfo.text != string.Empty)
            {

                words[i] = wordInfo.text;

                Wnlib.PartsOfSpeech[] posEnum = (Wnlib.PartsOfSpeech[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(Wnlib.PartsOfSpeech));

                for (int j = 0; j < posEnum.Length; j++)
                {
                    if (wordInfo.senseCounts[j] > 0) // get the first part of speech
                    {
                        wordInfos[i] = new MyWordInfo(words[i], posEnum[j]);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        WordSenseDisambiguator wsd = new WordSenseDisambiguator();
        wordInfos = wsd.Disambiguate(wordInfos);
```

When I view the results, the Sense for every word is still '0' :( Haas anyone used this before or can anyone figure out how to work the WordSenseDisambiguator? 
Thanks in anticipation of your hastened responses :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to try out WordNet::SenseRelate::AllWords, which does all words sense diambiguation using WordNet.

http://senserelate.sourceforge.net

Try it out via the web interface at

http://marimba.d.umn.edu

Comment: The web interface is showing 
`cannot connect to server 127.0.0.1:32323 (Connection refused)`. Is there any other server which is hosting it ?